# Django IntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have two tables Topmost and Pincode:

```
class Pincode(models.Model):
    pincode = models.CharField("PinCode", max_length=6, null=False)
    geom = GeopositionField("Location")

class Topmost(models.Model):
     pincode = models.ForeignKey(Pincode, unique=True)
     rating_pincode = models.CharField("Total Rating points", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
     frequency = models.CharField("Number of user", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
     normalized_rank = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Now i wanna create an automatic entry to topmost when new pincodes are created.
So in views.py:

```
id_past_entries = Topmost.objects.all().values_list('pincode_id', flat=True)
    new_entries = Pincode.objects.exclude(id__in=id_past_entries).values_list('id', flat=True)

    for new_id in new_entries:
        new = Pincode.objects.get(id = new_id)
        Topmost.objects.create(pincode=new,rating_pincode=0, frequency=0, normalized_rank=0 )
        Topmost().save()
```

But it gives error

> IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: display_topmost.pincode_id

Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

why are you using `Topmost().save()`?

`Topmost.objects.create(pincode=new,rating_pincode=0, frequency=0, normalized_rank=0 )` already creates your object

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't be doing TopMost().save() as the create function does the same thing. Secondly, just make sure all the PinCodes in the database have an id attached to them. This could be the reason why there is an integrity error of not null constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use signals in this case (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/
), remove code from view.py and add signal in models.py:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Pincode(models.Model):
    pincode = models.CharField("PinCode", max_length=6, null=False)
    geom = GeopositionField("Location")

class Topmost(models.Model):
    pincode = models.ForeignKey(Pincode, unique=True)
    rating_pincode = models.CharField("Total Rating points", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    frequency = models.CharField("Number of user", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    normalized_rank = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Pincode)
def create_topmost(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
       Topmost.objects.create(pincode=instance, rating_pincode="0", frequency="0", normalized_rank=0 )
```